# Google Chart Error: Object #<Object> has no method 'F'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, google-visualization

I'm trying to use google charts in my angular app. When I make the call I get a google visualization error:

[image]

In my controllers I have:

```
$scope.MakeQuery = function() {
    ....
    $scope.query = qs;
    $http.get('/api/query?' + $scope.query)
        .success((data) => {
            $scope.result = data;
        })
        .error((error) => {
            $scope.error = error;
        });

}
```

I then have the follwing directive:

```
tsafApp.directive("googleChart",function(){
    return {
        restrict : "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(elem[0]);
            var options = {
                width: 500,
                height: 500,
            };

            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(v) {
                 var dt = v.table;
                 console.log(v.table)
                 chart.draw(dt, options)
            });
        }
    }
});
```

In the partial I have the following (Which is where the visualization error appears when I make the query):

```
<div google-chart ng-model="result" class="chart"></div>
```

The object return in the console is as follows:

[image]

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My data wasn't actually a proper datatable. By adding the following I was able to coerce it:

```
scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function(v) {
    var dt = new google.visualization.DataTable(v.table);
    chart.draw(dt, options)
});
```

Found this in the following reference: [Populating Data Using Server-Side Code](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/php_example)